# Assign POST values to an array in a loop and put array into a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array containing the names of form input names:

```
$minmax = array('bed_min', 'bed_max', 'rec_min', 'rec_max', 'bath_min', 'bath_max', 'value_min', 'value_max');
```

The names are identical to the corresponding columns in a database. Instead of using an sql query like so:

```
$bed_min=$_POST['bed_min'];
$bed_max=$_POST['bed_max'];
$rec_min=$_POST['rec_min'];
$rec_max=$_POST['rec_max'];
$bath_min=$_POST['bath_min'];
$bath_max=$_POST['bath_max'];
$value_min=$_POST['value_min'];
$value_max=$_POST['value_max'];


$query = "UPDATE first_page SET bed_min='$bed_min', bed_max='$bed_max', rec_min='$rec_min', rec_max='$rec_max', bath_min='$bath_min', bath_max='$bath_max', value_min='$value_min', value_max='$value_max', WHERE email_address='$email' ";
```

Is there a way to automate all this into a smaller lump of code? I know the POST values should not be added to the query diectly, so maybe a loop to assign the POST values to a corresponding array of variables using something like:

```
foreach ($minmax as $var){
  $var = $_POST[$var]
}
```

(nb i dont think this snippet will work but ive added it because I think with a bit of editing it might!)

After the list of variables have been assigned the POST values, do the update in the $query using two arrays, one with the list of values and one with the list of database columns. Again I dont know how this will work, so pointers would be helpful!

Comment: Dat unsanitized query tho...

Comment: Look into prepared queries, http://us1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: yea forgot to mention, ignore sanitization - im getting the nuts and bolts working before adding that! (also trying my hardest to migrate from MYSQL to PDO....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that all of the values in post have the same names (array keys) as your columns, then something like this could work for you:

```
$query = "UPDATE first_page SET ";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $var){
  $query .= " $key='$var',";
}
$query = rtrim($query,',') . " WHERE email_address='$email' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the $minmax array of form input names since you can get those from the keys of $_POST.

If the values are all numbers, like they seem to be, then you could do it all in one line like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE first_page SET " . vsprintf(implode("='%d', ", array_keys($sanitized_POST))."='%d'", array_values($sanitized_POST))." WHERE email_address='$email'";
```

That's assuming you have already sanitized the items from $_POST into a new array named $sanitized_POST.  I know you said in the above comment to ignore sanitization, but I thought I'd add it so you know I'm not suggesting to use the values straight from $_POST.

You could sanitize the $_POST array with something like this:

```
$sanitized_POST = array_map(function($item) {

    return mysqli::real_escape_string($item);

}, $_POST);
```

Honestly though, you should try to come up with a solution that uses prepared statements.

On a side note, if you have the sanitized post array, then this one line will essentially do what Quixrick has done with variable variables in one of the other answers:

```
extract($sanitized_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use '[Variable Variables](https://www.php.net/variables.variable)' here.  Basically, you'd use a double dollar sign `$$` to create a variable with the name of the array value.

```
$_POST['bed_min'] = 'Rick';

$minmax = array('bed_min', 'bed_max', 'rec_min', 'rec_max', 'bath_min', 'bath_max', 'value_min', 'value_max');


foreach ($minmax as $var){
    $$var = $_POST[$var];
}

print "<BR>BED MIN: ".$bed_min;
```

This outputs:

```
BED MIN: Rick
```